# R Plyr Write CSV

Tags: r, loops, csv

I am trying to split a data frame and write it to a csv file in r using the unique values in one variable. I am new to r and I'm not entirely sure I know what I'm doing.

```
 ## trying to subset data
    library(dplyr)
    library(plyr)
    #set the working directory
    setwd("S:/some stuff")

    ## load the datafile into an object called data. 
    data <- read.csv("S:/some stuff/Area.csv",
                       header = TRUE, sep = ",")
#Create subsets of data by LA
LA<-subset(data,AREA == "LA")
```

My data frame has 2,500 observations and 20 variables.

My dataframe is called LA
The variable I'd like to split it by is called Disease

I found this [How to create multiple ,csv files in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126984/how-to-create-multiple-csv-files-in-r)

And reapproriated it accordingly

from

```
plyr::d_ply(iris, .(Species), function(x) write.csv(x, 
  file = paste(x$Species, ".csv", sep = "")))
```

to

```
plyr::d_ply(LA, .(Disease), function(x) write.csv(x,
file = paste(LA$Disease, ".csv", )))
```

However....

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :

 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
```

There are two things I'd like to solve. 
1) subsetting a dataframe 
2) writing to a path

Ideally I'd like to loop through it from the import of data (the Area.csv file).
This has areas and disease. There are 12 areas and 20 diseases. 
I would like to create csv files of each disease by area. 
In this example Area = LA and then disease.

How can I step through using a loop to create the 20 different files for each area?

I thought this:
https://blog.ouseful.info/2013/04/03/splitting-a-large-csv-file-into-separate-smaller-files-based-on-values-within-a-specific-column/

```
    mpExpenses2012 = read.csv("~/Downloads/DataDownload_2012.csv")
#mpExpenses2012 is the large dataframe containing data for each MP
#Get the list of unique MP names
for (name in levels(mpExpenses2012$MP.s.Name)){
  #Subset the data by MP
  tmp=subset(mpExpenses2012,MP.s.Name==name)
  #Create a new filename for each MP - the folder 'mpExpenses2012' should already exist
  fn=paste('mpExpenses2012/',gsub(' ','',name),sep='')
  #Save the CSV file containing separate expenses data for each MP
  write.csv(tmp,fn,row.names=FALSE)
}
```

might be helpful, but it's writing to a path that's getting me down.

EDIT

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
temp_dir <- tempfile()
dir.create(temp_dir)

LA %>%
  nest(-FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis) %>% 
  pwalk(function(FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis, data) write.csv(data, file.path(temp_dir, paste0(FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis, ".csv"))))
list.files(temp_dir)
temp_dir
unlink(temp_dir, recursive = T)
```

This works. But now comes the "where are the files?" question.
Yes: I get the temp file and then the unlink. 
But how do I save in a folder on S:/some stuff/

?

EDIT FINAL: SOLVED
I've read that in r everything is a list. And I found a way to split by two columns to do what I needed. Annoyingly it's linked in the comments in here:
https://blog.ouseful.info/2013/04/03/splitting-a-large-csv-file-into-separate-smaller-files-based-on-values-within-a-specific-column/

and I missed it. 
I was also having problems generating a dir using dir.create. Who knew that dir.create needs to have recursive = TRUE when you're trying to do stuff? I DO NOW.

Anyway. here's what I did:

```
## trying to subset data
# generate data:
library(tidyr)
    library(purrr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(write)
 ## set working directory
    setwd("S:/somestuff")

    #create the directories - pretty sure there's a way to avoid doing this long hand
    dir.create("S:/somestuff/CSV source files", recursive = TRUE)
    dir.create("S:/somestuff/CSV source files/LA1", recursive = TRUE)
    dir.create("S:/somestuff/CSV source files/LA2", recursive = TRUE)
    dir.create("S:/somestuff/CSV source files/LA3", recursive = TRUE)


    #Read in the CSV
    DF = read.csv("S:/somestuff/CSV source files/ALL.csv",
                       header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    glimpse(DF) 

    #This splits the dataframe generated above (DF) and calls it DF4
    DF4 <- split(DF,list(DF$LA,DF$FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis))
    lapply(names(DF4), function(name) write.csv(DF4[[name]], file = paste("S:/somestuff/CSV source files/",gsub('','',name),sep = ''), row.names = F))
```

I'm guessing if I read in the dataframe I could then use dir.create to create paths from the names in LA in the data frame.

After returning to the problem. It's much easier in the latest version of dplyr

```
ourdata<-DF4%>%
  group_by(DF$LA,DF$FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis)%>%
  group_walk(~ write_csv(.x, paste0(.y$LA,.y$FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis, ".csv")))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write multiple csv files by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620208/write-multiple-csv-files-by-group)

Comment: I agree it might be a possible comment about splitting, but it's the writing....

Comment: cderv's answer in the linked question addresses writing the files. The particular line is `pwalk(function(Rkey, data) write_csv(data, file.path(temp_dir, paste0(Rkey, ".csv"))))`

Comment: Ok. Let me have a look at that and if it works, I'll mark it as solved?

Comment: looks like it works, but i have a question about tempdir etc.

Comment: tempdir is only there to make the example reproducible. Use whatever folder you require.

Comment: I've tried this again. At home with simpler data.I get this:  Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I noticed the write_csv should be write.csv, is there anything else in the proposedsolution that I'm missing?I've specified the location of the file in tempfile() and the dir I want creating in createdir, i can even see the created dir....

Comment: I've solved this by using the code i've included in the final edit. If anyone would like to offer suggestions where I could speed up, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This was really helpful to me!  Thanks!!  I tried to simplify the crux of the matter.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(reprex)

states4 <- tribble(~state,~name,~area,
      "AL","Alabama",50645.3242,
      "AZ","Arizona",113594.0781,
      "AR","Arkansas",52035.4727,
      "CA","California",155779.2031
    )

chain4 <- states4 %>% split(.$state)

map(names(chain4),function(stateabbrev){write_csv(chain4[[stateabbrev]],paste0("~/Downloads/","testtoken_",stateabbrev,".csv"))})
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   state name      area
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 AL    Alabama 50645.
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   state name       area
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 AR    Arkansas 52035.
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   state name       area
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 AZ    Arizona 113594.
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   state name          area
#>   <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 CA    California 155779.

list.files(path="~/Downloads", pattern = "testtoken.*csv")
#> [1] "testtoken_AL.csv" "testtoken_AR.csv" "testtoken_AZ.csv"
#> [4] "testtoken_CA.csv"

reprex()
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm glad it was useful to you! Your solution looks very neat!

Comment: Thanks! It is very few lines of code altho it does not have the directory making that you need :-).  The purr::map is basically the same as lapply in this instance i think.

Comment: Alternatively : 

After returning to the problem. It's much easier in the latest version of dplyr

`DF4%>%
      group_by(DF$LA,DF$FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis)%>%
      group_walk(~ write_csv(.x, paste0(.y$LA,.y$FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis, ".csv"))) `

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used:

```
## trying to subset data
# generate data:
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library (car)
## set working directory
setwd("S:/Somestuff/Borough profile maps/Working")

## read data in from geocoded file
geocoded<-read.csv("geocoded 2015 - 2018.csv",na.strings=c(""," ","N/A"))

str(geocoded)
str(geocoded$GENDER)
levels(geocoded$LA)

#split geocoded data by LA 
x <-split(geocoded,geocoded$LA)
str(x)

#Split geocoded data by LA and Final
#split(x, f, drop = FALSE, sep = ".", lex.order = FALSE, .)
y<-split(geocoded,list(geocoded$Final,geocoded$LA), drop = TRUE, sep = "_")
str(y)

#create dir and then write CSV files of geocoded to file locations
dir.create("S:/Somestuff/Borough profile maps/Working/TEST/",, recursive = TRUE)
dir.create("S:/Somestuff/Borough profile maps/Working/TEST/TEST2",, recursive = TRUE)
lapply(names(x), function(name) write.csv(x[[name]], file = paste('S:/Somestuff/Borough profile maps/Working/TEST/',gsub(' ','',name),sep = ''), row.names = F))
lapply(names(y),function(name) write.csv(y[[name]], file = paste('S:/Somestuff/Borough profile maps/Working/TEST/TEST2/',name,".csv")))
```

The problem was that in my original code you'll notice I was using read.csv BUT feeding in a .txt file. I changed the file to .csv and BANG. it worked. First time.

I realise that you don't need all the libraries I called at the beginning, but they're left in from my ridiculous number of attempts.

Answer (score 0):

After returning to the problem. It's much easier in the latest version of dplyr

```
DF4%>%
      group_by(DF$LA,DF$FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis)%>%
      group_walk(~ write_csv(.x, paste0(.y$LA,.y$FinalDiseaseForMonthlyAnalysis, ".csv")))
```